# Session in PHP in Social Engine

Tags: php, mysql, session, socialengine

I have this query in mysql in a php page:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tz_todo SET text='".$text."', 
                                     position = ".$position.", 
                                     user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].", 
                                     view_stat=0");
```

I tried to echo the query and the result is this:

```
INSERT INTO tz_todo SET text='trial text', position = 21, user_id=, view_stat=0
```

it seems that it can't get the session value of `user_id`.

And `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not working in social engine. How to correct this? I also made a localhost version in my xampp and everything is fine but when I converted it into social engine, session is not working.

Comment: do you call `session_stat();` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Check to see if there are any native social engine functions for handling session and use them to store/get information from there.

Comment: @David Yes. I started the session already.

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 That is the problem with social engine. Im really new to social engine and they don't have much articles ang tutorials.

Comment: any errors? `error_reporting(-1);` and make sure they are visible (display_errors)

Comment: is the session variable definitely already set?

Comment: @cohen yep2 I really checked it. it seems social engine is not storing the session value in my customized widget

Answer (score 2):

In any page where you are using session objects, place this code at the beginning of the file:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
```

This way if the session is not already started, it starts it; otherwise it ignores the session start if the sesion is already started.
This is important because calling session_start() if session is started already can sometimes cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I get my user id through session

```
session_start();

$userID = $viewer->getIdentity();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userID;

echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using session to store the user_id is totally wrong. To gain a user_id try

`$viewer_id = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity();` (or $user->getIdentity if you have another user's object).

If you still need to use session for storing this data, use [Zend-approach](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.storage.html).

Comment: $user = Engine_Api::_()->getItem('user', $user_id); usually getting users full object is better.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> session_start(); 
> $_SESSION["test"] = "hello world";
> ```

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["test"];
```

does above code work ? if not, check your **session.save_path** in the php.ini

NOTE: to retain this variable remember to call session_start() on each php script/page before calling for the variable from the session.

Comment: the code works but the social engine won't retain the value of the session.

Comment: Look into this link : http://www.socialengineforum.com/index.php?/topic/15992-bug-fix-your-session-configuration-is-incorrect/

Answer (score 0):

Yoy might be forget to start your session at the top of the page

> `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); } ?>`

$_SESSION['user_id'] might not stored a value. check your login page (Basically after login session variables will set) or after register weather you assigned a value to that session variable..

setting a value to a session variable :

> $_SESSION['user_id'] = "1234567";